# ServiceStack Client on Xamarin.Mac (not iOS)

Tags: servicestack, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac Unified API project with ServiceStack Client v4.0.38. I get the good old "System.ArgumentException: PclExport.Instance needs to be initialized" when trying to instantiate JsonServiceClient.

If I was on iOS, I would call IosPclExportClient.Configure() and life would be good. However, I can't find the equivalent for Mac. I would expect something like MacPclExportClient.Configure().

Any idea how to get the ServiceStack Client to work on Xamarin.Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The `IosPclExportClient` should still be [available for Unified API Projects](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/blob/master/src/Client.iOS10.Pcl/Main.cs#L15) as well, e.g:

```
ServiceStack.IosPclExportClient.Configure();
```

Comment: @RonPeters ahh annoying, Xamarin.Mac uses a unique NuGet profile so wasn't pulling in the compatible iOS Unified API packages. This has now been added on the [latest packages on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) otherwise you can manually reference the .dll directly from the NuGet packages folder at: `/packages/ServiceStack.Client.4.0.38/lib/Xamarin.iOS10/ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll`

Comment: This seems to work fine in debug mode, but with SDK linking enabled we're encountering:
   `<AppPath>.Mac/MMP: Error MM2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' (MM2002) (<AppName>.Mac)`

@mythz the Xamarin.iOS dll is not available in a Xamarin.Mac app when it's built for release and linking is enabled.  I've tried adding the ServiceStack.Client package and copying the dll(s) manually as you suggest, and the result is the same.